# Call WCF service from silverlight client using a non-UI thread

Tags: wpf, silverlight

I have a pretty simple scenario:
I have an asynchronous WCF service calls in my silverlight app.
I want to execute those on a separate thread ( or similar) because they freeze up my UI.
All service calls are meant to update the ViewModel thus the/ a UI control on the page, so need to find a way to do that from the thread running the service calls without getting the familiar cross thread exception.
Any suggestions?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dispatcher.BeginInvoke is the best solution.

Partial defination of service proxy:

```
public void GetItemById(int id, Action<ItemModel> callback)
{
    AsyncCallback onCompleted = ar => 
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => 
            callback(this.Channel.EndGetItemById(ar)));
    this.Channel.BeginGetItemById(id, onCompleted, null);
}
```

Call from MVVM:

```
var proxy = new MyServiceProxy();
proxy.GetItemById(5, item => this.Item = item);
```

Answer (score 3):

In talking with folks on the WCF team, this is my understanding about how it works.  If you simply make the call from a background thread, it won't work, as the WCF subsystem will marshal the call back onto the thread from which you initially opened the connection (normally, the UI thread).  So what you have to do is create a worker thread, and then explicitly open the connection *from that thread*.  Then, whenever you make a call, it will get marshaled back onto that thread.  And of course, once you've received your callback and done your processing (on the background thread), then make sure that you marshal any UI changes back onto the UI thread using Dispatcher.BeginInvoke().

Comment: You just made my day. I had a situation where I wanted to wait the UI thread on a handle that would be set by a handler of a WCF call completion. Well, that call completion never came because the call itself couldn't even start until after that very wait!

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28VS.95%29.aspx), or make your client proxy support the [Asynchronous Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734701.aspx).

Make sure you dispatch UI updates to the proper thread as described here:
http://russelleast.wordpress.com/2010/02/27/using-wcf-async-pattern-with-silverlight-3/